# How to get the quantity of the product chosen by the user?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on an e-commerce website. Now I am on single product description page and I have quantity and add to cart button. Initial quantity I set one.

[image]

I am able to increase and decreased the quantity on click on plus and minus button.

[image]

Now the issue is, I choose quantity four and I clicked on add to cart button and it redirects to checkout page where I am checking the output

**checkout.php**

Just for testing

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo $action=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['action']);
    echo $decrypted_p_id=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['p_id']);
}
```

**I got an output**

```
   addcart
    1      //instated of one It should display four. right?
```

I know I will get one because I set the value="1" but is there any other option 
to get the quantity whatever user choose?

Or do you have any other code to do this?

Thanks you!

```js
/*increase the product qty*/
/*increase the product qty*/
  $(".ddd").on("click", function () {
    var $button = $(this),
        $input = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quntity-input");
    var oldValue = $input.val(),
        newVal;
    if ($.trim($button.text()) == "+") {
        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue > 1) {
            newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
            newVal = 1;
        }
    }
    $input.val(newVal);
    var price = $('.total_amount').data('price');
    $('.total_amount').html(price * newVal);
});
```

```css
.sp-quantity {
    width:150px;
     float: left;
    height:42px;  
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.sp-minus {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

.sp-input {
    border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-left:0px solid black;
    float:left;
}

.sp-plus {
width: 41px;
height: 40px;
border: 1px solid #f44336;
float: left;
margin-left: -1px;
text-align: center;
}

.sp-input input {
    width:40px;
    height:39px;
    text-align:center;
    border: none;
}

.sp-input input:focus {
    border:1px solid #f44336;
    border: none;
}

.sp-minus a, .sp-plus a {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 2px;
font-size: 22px;
color: #fff;
background: #f44336;
}
.product-details .cart button {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f44336;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color: #fff;
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
    <main class="product-details">
        <section class="pro-detail-sec">
                        <!-- counter and cart div -->
                        <div class="counter-cart clearfix">
                                <div class="sp-quantity">
                                    <div class="sp-minus fff"><a class="ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="-1">-</a></div>
                                    <div class="sp-input">
                                        <input type="text" class="quntity-input" value="1" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="sp-plus fff"><a class="ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="1">+</a></div>
                                </div>

                            <!-- add to car -->
                            <div class="cart">
                                <form action="test15.php" method="POST">
                                  <button type="submit" name="submit">Add to cart</button>
                                  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addcart"/>
                                  <input type="hidden" name="p_id" value="1"/>
                                </form>

                          </div>
                        </div>

        </section>
      </main>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Isn't `p_id` your product id? If not, how would you know what product to add?

Comment: Yes, p_id is my product id

Comment: I just want to pass the quantity on the next page and in the form tag, I have add to cart and product id field.

Comment: All you need to do is to put the quantity input inside your form and it will be submitted together with the rest of the inputs.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ You should use Prepared Statements instead of escaping and concatenating your DB-queries. Even `mysqli_real_escape_string()` have security issues in certain situations.

Comment: but how can I insert the input filed inside? should I use hidden field? If yes then how can I pass the quantity value? Yes, I am using a prepared statement.

Comment: 1. Just move your form tags to wrap around all your inputs. Move the open form tag to right after `<!-- counter and cart div -->` and the closing form tag after the closing div. 2. Give the quantity input a name (or it won't be submitted) 3. If you're using prepared statements, then you should not escape the values. Prepared statements will take care of that for you (if you're using parameterized placeholders, that is).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, Yes I tried whatever you suggested me and I get the value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165923/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-magnus-eriksson).

Answer (score 0):

You should place the

```
<input type="text" class="quntity-input" value="1" />
```

element inside your form in order to submit the selected quantity when clicking the "Add to cart" button. An alternative would be setting the value of the "p_id" input element to the desired quantity in your javscript code when incrementing or decrementing the value.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're not updating `p_id` value when increasing/decreasing it.

```
var qty = $("#p_id");
  $(".ddd").on("click", function() {
    var $button = $(this),
      $input = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quntity-input");
    var oldValue = $input.val(),
      newVal;
    if ($.trim($button.text()) == "+") {
      newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
      // Don't allow decrementing below zero
      if (oldValue > 1) {
        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
      } else {
        newVal = 1;
      }
    }
    $input.val(newVal);
    var price = $('.total_amount').data('price');
    $('.total_amount').html(price * newVal);
    qty.val(newVal);
  });
```

Now, when you'll increase or decrease user quantity, it will update `p_id` input value, which is the one you are retrieving from PHP

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yep, but it's what he's retrieving from PHP expecting to be product quantity, who knows

Comment: Yes, p_id is my product id, not quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is updating the value of the input with class `.quntity-input`, but you are looking at your hidden field with the name p_id.

You can't submit input that are not inside the form tag which is why `.quntity-input` is not being submitted. You need to also update the value of the input with name p_id if you want that to reflect the new value.